# How can I invoke a function inside class outside of the class

Tags: javascript

I have created a class with a constructor and a method, I'm trying to create new instances and to use the inner function but it doesn't work, i'm new to JavaScript

I have tried to do this with getting the function outside of the class but i'm trying to do it while it's inside

```
class Jewel {
    constructor(type, price) {
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
    }
    getHigherPrice(jewel1Price, jewel2Price) {
        if (jewel1Price > jewel2Price) {
            return jewel1.price;
        } else {
            return jewel2.price;
        }
    }
}
let biggerPrice = Jewel.getHigherPrice(new Jewel("bracelet", 300), new Jewel("ring", 200));
```

I want it to print the bigger price but it prints the second one

Comment: I can't see any code where you're calling `getHigherPrice`; can you show us what you tried? (Please [edit] the question, don't add it as a comment.)

Comment: sorry, at the bottom

Comment: You can't call the function from the class name unless the function is static.

Comment: 1) You're looking for a `static` method. 2) You're passing instances of `Jewel` into `getHigherPrice`, but you're treating them as if they were a number. The names of the arguments and their use do not correspond.

Comment: I wouldn't put that method in the class. I'd have it as a normal function declaration that accepts two Jewel instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `static` method that takes two instances of `Jewel` class, compare their prices and returns the bigger price. You call static method on class instead of class instance.

```js
class Jewel {
  constructor(type, price) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
  }

  static getHigherPrice(a, b) {
    return a.price > b.price ? a.price : b.price;
  }
}
let biggerPrice = Jewel.getHigherPrice(
  new Jewel("bracelet", 300),
  new Jewel("ring", 200)
);

console.log(biggerPrice)
```

Comment: Thank it workde like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method:

```
static getHigherPrice(jewel1Price, jewel2Price) {...}
```

Also change your code to deal with `Jewel`s:

```js
class Jewel {
  constructor(type, price) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
  }
  static getHigherPrice(jewel1, jewel2) {
    if (jewel1.price > jewel2.price) {
      return jewel1.price;
    } else {
      return jewel2.price;
    }
  }
}
let biggerPrice = Jewel.getHigherPrice(new Jewel("bracelet", 300), new Jewel("ring", 200));
console.log(biggerPrice);
```

And you can simplify this by simply using destructuring and `Math.max`:

```js
class Jewel {
  constructor(type, price) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
  }
  static getHigherPrice({ price: a }, { price: b }) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }
}
let biggerPrice = Jewel.getHigherPrice(new Jewel("bracelet", 300), new Jewel("ring", 200));
console.log(biggerPrice);
```